# How to close magnific popup by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m using a magnific popup in my project. To close this popup by jQuery I am using
`$('.mfp-close').click();` and it's working but I have need to close by another way.

Please help me if any other way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some of your code

Answer (score 50):

Just use `$.magnificPopup.close()`

Answer (score 41):

try this:

```
var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance; 
// save instance in magnificPopup variable
magnificPopup.close(); 
// Close popup that is currently opened
```

Comment: how do you do that ? i just get null on var maginificPopup

Comment: show me a jsfiddle with your problem. Normally this should work every time.

Comment: is there an actual need to declare the instance ?, cause in [other answer, from user Kote](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20678572/2615737), that line is not needed.

Comment: it is not mandatory, but I do this usually if I need to do more than one thing with the current popup. So it depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 16):

Take a look here http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

These are some ways you can close this pop up:

```
var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance; // save instance in magnificPopup variable
magnificPopup.close(); // Close popup that is currently opened
```

or

`$.magnificPopup.close();`

or

`$('your-selector').magnificPopup('close');`

For me,  only the third one worked efficiently.

Comment: Technique #3 was the only one I could get to work right to target a specific popup and not all of them. Thanks, Lem!

Answer (score 5):

The only one that works for me is :

```
$jQ('#close_popup').on('click',function(){                                                      
    $jQ.magnificPopup.proto.close.call(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have open the `pop up` then it will return an `magnific object`,
Using that `object` you can `call` `close method`.

Try it like,

```
var mgObj=$('your-selecter').magnificPopup({
   // you options
});

// code to close pop up on clicking a button
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    if(mgObj)
    {
        mgObj.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thanks for ur reply.
When I m using it, it throws mgObj.close() is not a function.
Can u provide me solution.

Answer (score 0):

`magnificPopup` iframe:

```js
window.parent.$.magnificPopup.close();
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I could make the popup close:

```
$('body').on('click', '#some-div', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```